# How to apply styles in nested lists ordered numbers separately?

Tags: html, css

Lets say we have an `<ol>` and `<li>` nested inside a parent `<li>` of a parent `<ol>`.

It creates something like this :

```html
<html>
<body>
<ol class="ol1">
<li>li 1 - ol 1<ol class = "ol1-1"><li>li 1 - ol 1.1</li></ol></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to apply css styles in the list numbers (not the content) separately,i only know how to get both of them using pseudo css element`:before` but not separately,for example OL-1 to be `color:blue` and OL-1.1 to be `color:red`

Comment: [link](https://www.lockedownseo.com/ordered-list-ol-different-color-for-numbers/) try this link

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a seperate class for each level of "ol" element then apply the css to the "class li::marker".

```html
<html>
  <style>
     .ol1 li::marker{
       color:blue;
     }

     .ol1-1 li::marker{
       color:red;
     }
  </style>

  <body>
    <ol class="ol1">
      <li>li 1 - ol 1
         <ol class = "ol1-1">
           <li>li 1 - ol 1.1</li>
         </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Custom numbering does'nt work as expected,any ideas ?

.ol1 {
          counter-reset: my-custom-counter;
          
          position: relative;
          left: 200px;
      }
     .ol1 li::marker{
       color:blue;
         font-size: 55px;
         content: "HOTEL " counter(my-custom-counter)" ";
  counter-increment: my-custom-counter;
     } 

     .ol1-1 li::marker{
       color:red;
       position: relative;
       
     }

Answer (score 0):

you mean someting like:

```
.ol1 > .ol1-1 li{
   color:red;
}
```

this makes every "li" after .ol1-1, that's a children of .oli1 color red. Or at least it should.